# how to use secondary storage path for creating repositories in SVN

Tags: linux, shell, svn, ubuntu-16.04, tortoisesvn

we have single ubuntu server. svn is installed and we are creating SVN repos and its storing in below storage path.
path1 : /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root)

now we added HDD of 1TB to (/dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb) this path.

now the challenge is how can i use this newly added storage for creating svn repos for new projects. without interrupting existing svn storage location.

path2:/dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the parent directory /dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb exists and that you have sufficient permissions to modify that directory, the previous command creates a new repository in the directory /dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb/repos,

You can explicitly choose the filesystem type using the --fs-type argument, which accepts as a parameter either **fsfs** or **bdb**. **( check for yours )**

`svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb/repos`

User the user fro which snv was installed in first place

`$ chown svn:svn -R /dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb/repos`

You might want to control permissions in “/dev/mapper/vgsvnsdb-lvsvnsdb/repos”. Make sure authz-db = authz is enabled in svnserv.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. let me check this